# Register custom filters with vue.js

Tags: javascript, browserify, javascript-framework, vue.js, laravel-elixir

I am using Vue.js with Laravel with Elixir and Browserify. I want to register some custom global filters, each in their own file. I tried to follow the docs, but I can't get it to work. This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

vue/filters/reverse.js

```
Vue.filter('reverse', function (value) {
 return value.split('').reverse().join('')
})
```

vue/app.js

```
var Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));

new Vue({
    el: 'app',
    data: {
        test: 'abcde'
    },
filters: {
    reverse: require './filters/reverse.js'
}

});
```

View

```
<h1 v-text="test | reverse"></h1>
```

If I add this in reverse.js, it still doesn't work

```
var Vue = require('vue');
```

And my gulpfile

```
    mix.browserify('app.js');
```

Comment: Where are you including the scripts in your blade template?  Also, can you share the relevant lines of code from your gulpfile?

Comment: what if you use : require './filters/reverse.js' instead ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I actually meant to write './filters/reverse.js'

Comment: Just updated my question @Douglas.Sesar

Comment: Try to manually include Vue.js via CDN to narrow down if there is a browserify issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this in vue/filters/reverse.js

```
module.exports =(function (value) {
  return value.split('').reverse().join('')
})
```

And then in your app.js

```
Vue.filter('reverse', require('./filters/reverse'))
```

Comment: @Michalis Antoniou is that not what you want? If you don't want it to be global, just add parentheses around your file name, that should work like `reverse: require( './filters/reverse.js')`